# How do I assign a v-for element to an HTML video src?

Tags: html, vue.js, video, v-for

I'm trying to get a different video for each item within my v-for loop but it won't work.

```html
<section v-if="loaded" class="port-content">
      <div class="item-box reveal" v-for="item in this.items" v-bind:key="item.title">
        ...
        <div class="item-vid-wrapper">
          <video controls>
            <source :src="item.vidPath" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

The vidPath variable in item is '../assets/homeVid.mp4'.

Normally, setting a path in the src element would start from the folder of this .vue file. So if my path was '../assets/homeVid.mp4', it would go to the parent and into the assets folder. This successfully sets the homeVid.mp4 video to all the v-for elements:

```
<source src="../assets/homeVid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

When I try to set it dynamically using item.vidPath, it seems to be doing a GET request to localhost instead, ignoring the '..', and trying to find the video from there:

[image: console output]

How do I assign item.vidPath to the video src as if I was hardcoding the path?

Comment: The issue here is `:key="item.title"`, you need to have something unique there, like a UUID.

Comment: If you don't have anything like a UUID, you can always use `item.vidPath` for the `:key`, should not be an issue. The only thing is for it to be unique.

Comment: That does solve the duplicate keys issue, but setting the src path still shows the same error.

Comment: You should probably use `~` rather than `../`. The error seems to indicate that your current path is wrong, double check that. Also, you're using Vue2 or 3 (more precisely: Webpack or Vite)?

Comment: Vue2, I'll try that!

Comment: Try this-            `:src="require('@/assets/homeVid.mp4')"`

Comment: That worked! For future reference, what does the @ symbol signify? The parent folder?

Comment: `@` means that it's the root of your project. Or your `src` directory, depending on the setup of the alias in your bundle config file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

It doesn't work if I set the item.vidPath to '@/assets/homeVid.mp4' and do:

```
:src="require(item.vidPath)"
```

But if item.vidPath is just equal to 'homeVid.mp4' and the start of the string is harcoded, it works:

```
:src="require('@/assets/' + item.vidPath)
```

So it looks like this in the v-for loop:

```
<section v-if="loaded" class="port-content">
      <div class="item-box reveal" v-for="item in this.items" v-bind:key="item._id">
        <div class="item-info-wrapper">
          <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
          <div class="tag-row">
            <h3 v-for="tag in item.tags" v-bind:key="tag">{{ tag }}</h3>
          </div>
          <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
           <a href=item.repoLink></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-vid-wrapper">
          <video :src="require('@/assets/' + item.vidPath)" type="video/" controls>
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```